# How to deploy a PHP + Webpack application on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, webpack, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-app-engine-php

I have a PHP + React JS application that I'm trying to get deployed via Google App Engine Standard.  I've set the app.yaml to use php73 though I'm using Webpack to package the JS via yarn (actually, using Symfony Encore, but that shouldn't matter).

For the time being, I am using webpack locally and pushing those files up to GAE as a workaround, but I'd rather they be packed on GAE itself.  Am I able to somehow execute shell commands for a `gcloud app deploy` so that yarn executes the scripts I want?  Is creating a separate service with nodejs running just so it executes `package.json` scripts necessary, then deploying both PHP and nodejs services?

Answer (score 1):

You can [run custom build steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step) in Google App Engine by adding a "gcp-build" script in your package.json.

Example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "npm run gcp-build",
    "pretest": "npm run gcp-build",
    "test": "repo-tools test app -- index.js",
    "posttest": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "tslint -p .",
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "gcp-build": "tsc -p .",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy"   }
```

Also you can also set the runtime to [install specific dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#dependencies) using yarn, by using `yarn add PACKAGE` so a "yarn.lock" file is auto-generated. If App Engine finds a "yarn.lock" in the application directory, Yarn will be used to perform the npm installation

I'd also recommend that you check the following community tutorials:

- [Run Symfony on Google App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard)
- [Using Yarn on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-yarn)

In addition to checking the [Symfony Demo Application](https://github.com/symfony/demo) code that might be a good example.